# How to Blurr required Visuals in Power BI Repots for the first page load

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

> I am looking for an approach to blurr the visuals in power bi report.
> Please can someone suggest how can we implement below functionalities
> in Power BI Reports.
>
> 1. When the report load for the first time, some of the visuals should be in Blurr state until user click on the page.
> 2. If not required, need to blurr the visuals again.

Comment: This functionality is not available in Power BI, the closest method would be to use spotlight mode on a visual, that will show one and fade the others, until click on the page
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-spotlight

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can make a large shape and put it to the background. Add an action to the shape with bookmarks.
Create shapes over your visuals with a little of transparancy and in the bookmark make them dissapear.

When a user then clicks on the page the bookmark is triggered to unhide the shapes over the visuals.

Quite some work, but it will do what you want.